# JQuery is duplicating my comment every time I click

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I've created  script which loads a comment section every time a user adds a new comment or deletes a comment.

The deleting works perfectly but when I add a comment the script adds 1 comment the first time I click submit, 2 comments the next time, 5 the next, 10 on the next, ect....

I can't figure out why it's duplicating the comments like this.

Here is my code:

```
    function refreshComments(r_id) {
    var ar = $("#arr" + r_id).attr("class");
    $("#cali" + r_id).load("../functions/inC.php",{"id" : r_id,"ar" : ar},function() {          


   var link = $("#dani #delete" + r_id);
   $(link).click(function() {
   c_id = $(this).attr("class");

  $(".loading" + r_id).load("../functions/delete.php",{"id" : c_id});
  refreshComments(r_id);
   return false;
   });

$( "#internal" + r_id ).button();
$("#internal" + r_id).click(function () {
 $(".loading" + r_id).html('<img src="../img/ajax-loader.gif" style="width:100px; margin-top: 10px;" />');
      var comment = "";
      var comment = $("#comment" + r_id).val();
      var status = "public";
      alert(comment);

  $(".loading" + r_id).load("../functions/addMessage.php",{"id" : r_id,"comment" : comment, "status" : status});
   refreshComments(r_id);
      return false;
             });

    return false;   

    });


}
```

Ideally I would like to just append the actual comment to the top of the list but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting example code. However, I cannot fully determine the problem by looking at that because I don't know what your back end does.

From your problem description, a possible reason might be that you are not just loading the comments, but also keeping the previously loaded comments. That would look like the repetition.

You have 0 comments. You see 0 comments. Submit comment, download them all and you add 1.

You have 1 comments. You see 1 comment. Submit comment, download them all and you add 2.

You have 2 comments. You see 3 comments. Submit comment, download them all and you add 3.

You have 3 comments. You see 6 comments. Submit comment, download them all and you add 4.

You have 4 comments. You see 10 comments. etc

Does this look like your problem?